# Cannot read properties of my telegram bot (php://input)

Tags: php, http, telegram-bot

i've got such a weird problem.
I'm trying to develop a telegram bot, and I set the webhook just before, it gave me OK response.

Once done that, I tried to code the following:

```
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($update);
$update = json_decode($update, true);
```

The var_dump of $update returns an empty string.
I've watched many tutorials and i don't actually understand why it doesn't work for me.
If I try to call it from URL (https://api.telegram.org/bot......../getUpdates it works fine.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php, think you need 'php://output'

Answer (score 0):

How did you call your script? A simple http request via URL from your browser or  running it from command line will not print anything. That's because `file_get_contents('php://input')` looks for POST data. Which is missing in this case.

Maybe you want to do this:

Change your script:

```
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
error_log($update);
$update = json_decode($update, true);
```

Send a message to your bot via chat. And then check your php log files. You should see a json response with relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me it works on other servers but. Doesn't on a particular server so what I did was to disable the mod security on the particular cpanel and it worked perfectly. I hope this saves someone's time